# React native: watchID: ?number = null what is this syntax?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I was reading react native doc and I came across this line of code

`watchID: ?number = null;`

I know this is kind of `TypeScript` syntax but I can't see `TypeScript` being used in `React Native`.

Can someone please explain about this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is [Facebook flow](https://flowtype.org/) syntax. It's a way of introducing typing into regular Javascript. The source files can be statically parsed by flow to check for type problems. Then, when you compile your code with Babel, it takes these Flow annotations out so that it doesn't cause errors. You should see a `.flowconfig` file in your project's root directory—that's a dead giveaway your project is using flow.

This specific syntax is saying that if `watchId` is passed, it will be a `number` type, but the `?` indicates that this is also a `maybe` type, meaning it may not be passed, in which case the `= null` will happen (this is not flow-related), which is how you assign a default value in JS.

Comment: Thank you @Rob Wise